# Refresh view when app opens for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I would like to refresh a view when I open the app.  When I'm on the page I want to refresh then close the app and reopen it I won't refresh.  I tried putting the refresh in viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, and viewDidLoad but it nevers gets in there when I reopen.

Comment: What does your refresh code look like? "it never gets there" is a bad description.

Comment: I have breakpoints setup in each of the 3 methods and it doesn't hit them.  The refresh just hits an api then loads the data in to a table.  It works fine when I hit the refresh button, just not when I open the app.

Comment: Does viewWillAppear *ever* get called? Where is this view controller, on the navigation stack, presented modally...?

Comment: viewWillAppear gets called initially when the app is started but not when I close the app and then go back in to it.  And yes, the view controller is be presented modally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `UIApplicationDelegate`, implement `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`, and send a message to the view controller whose view is in need of update.